# Can you link subpages in Live server extension Visual studio code

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im new to web development and i am stil learning. 
Currently im creating a website with subpages and when i click on a link to a subpage i get this error.

`Cannot GET /login.html`

Im running my projects with Live server extension in visual studio code. Is there a way to link subpages and that Live server reckognizes them and runs them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out its better to run code with XAMPP server as long as you put all files in the same folder you will be able to access them

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in sever page:

`app.get("/login", function (req, res){
res.render("login");
});`

when you send a request to the server to access a page by using this code the server will render your request.